# What is the purpose of an UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

Why do we actually need a user control?

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <wpfApplication1:SaveCloseUserControl />

</Window>
```

User control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SaveCloseUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Height="30" Content="Save" />
    <Button Height="30"
            Margin="1"
            Content="Cancel" />
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class SaveCloseUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SaveCloseUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I don’t see any reason why should I wrap a StackPanel (or any other control) inside of a UserControl, if the following code without UserControl will do exactly the same.

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <wpfApplication1:SaveCloseStackPanel />

</Window>
```

Stack panel without user control:

```
<StackPanel x:Class="WpfApplication1.SaveCloseUserControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Height="30" Content="Save" />
    <Button Height="30"
            Margin="1"
            Content="Cancel" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class SaveCloseUserControl : StackPanel
 {
    public SaveCloseUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

I’ve been using UserControls everywhere, but now when I think about it, they don’t do anything apart from wrapping an item in it. So I tried it on 10 different views, and does not matter what it is, I was able to replace the UserControl with other items (Grid, ComboBox, GroupBox etc), and it all works exactly the same way. So to be clear, if I had a user control and first thing in it was ComboBox, then I removed UserControl and put ComboBox in its place. Everything inside then stayed as it was, just like the above example with StackPanel.

Why would I even bother with UserControl, and have another item to be created and rendered if it does not do anything?

Comment: How would you re-use that component in multiple places while providing its own set of things like data validation rules and other viewmodel agnostic functionality? Ah haaa.... :D

Comment: @ChrisW. Exactly the same way as with usercontrol, because all I did is, I replaced the tag UserControl with StackPanel in this case (the begining and closing tag of a xaml file). Validation, binding etc, everything works as it was.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't notice you were already creating your own class. Then yea I see your point. I guess the argument would lean more towards code maintenance concerns then to since I know if I had to step in new to a BIG project and found stuff clumped together in non-standard ways, I'd cry a little on the inside lol. Except unless someone can provide a technically defined answer I could see this becoming a chatty discussion of opinion kind of question.

Comment: Yes it will work but using UserControl is like using The Person class instead of the Manager class even though the Manager is a Person. We should go to the top of the class hierarchy as much as we can. Stack panel is a user control but it is a special user control not a general one.

Comment: @OmarZaarour This is not the same to me, because if I use UserControl and then StackPanel inside it. I've created 2 objects instead of one, while there is no need for one of them which does not do anything. So I don't quite get the analogy between the Person/Manager of your comment and my question, but thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Actually I was wrong, the two don't follow the same inheritance tree. The only difference from my quick research is that with StackPanel you derive from the Layout control but with UserControl you derive from a Content control. In the former, you are enforcing a layout (a stack in stackpanel) and no layout in user control. So basically, if you add something to your StackControl the layout is kind of forced.

Comment: Lots of responses have alluded to this. In one word, re-usability.

Comment: In the second example, you have `<wpfApplication1:SaveCloseStackPanel />`, but `<StackPanel x:Class="WpfApplication1.SaveCloseUserControl" …>` and `public partial class SaveCloseUserControl : StackPanel`. I guess all should be `SaveCloseStackPanel`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The purpose of a `UserControl` is to **group** a set of controls into one, reusable component. They **cannot** be styled or templated.

The purpose of a `Custom Control` is to **extend** an existing control, or to create a brand new control. These, as opposed to a `UserControl` **can** be styled and templated.

I think you're getting mixed up with the two.

So, you may be wondering, *"When should I use a `UserControl` and when should I use a `Custom Control`?"* and the answer to that is it depends.

You should use a `UserControl` when you need to create a logical group of controls which interact in some way to create an almost *composite* control. You should use a `Custom Control` when you want to **add** functionality to an existing control.

In your example, your best approach would be to use a `UserControl`, as your `StackPanel` is a *group* of controls made into one reusable component.

You can find out a bit more [here](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html), and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the difference, I simply don't see the need to use a UserControl at all. If the first item in the UserControl can as well take place of the user control. And then it behaves exactly the same way, I can resuse it etc, but in return I get one less control, which must be a good thing.

Comment: In addition to Mike's comments, Make a user control only when u know that such congregation of controls will be needed by you over and over again. Another user case for User Controls is simply the views in the MVVM development. All your views are nothing but a congregation of controls and can be reused.

Comment: @adminSoftDK, the logical extension of your argument would imply that we don't need struct or class (abstract data types, in general), because they are "merely" aggregating more elementary types and associated behaviors. Aggregation of simpler 'things' - whether they be controls or simpler data types, and any related 'logic' that ties them together, is a very valuable OOP facility. User controls provide exactly this. Of course, if your needs are rather simple, user controls may be an overkill (much like a struct or a class can be an overkill sometimes), but it is quite useful at other times.

Comment: @adminSoftDK, I also think that you disregard the first statement of this answer. If you use a certain panel it could be a different result as that panel could be globally styled in the project. You cant have that problem with the UserControl

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `UserControl` is to help you build **reusable UI components** that can be added to your toolbox just like a built-in control, starting from nothing.
The prefix "User" here kinda means "Not from the WPF team". WPF does not ship any class that derives from `UserControl`.

A very important aspect of UserControls is you can design them using XAML (so they can be composite), and pack code + XAML together, possibly in a "library" assembly that you can ship without the source.

Now, your examples are quite anemic (no offence :-), they don't do anything so interesting that I would be tempted to make them really reusable. Most of the time, you will build UserControls from usage (or experience), after having realized that you have repeated the same XAML pattern more than once, maybe with a few variation.

For example in this open source project (Github for Visual Studio): https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/tree/master/src/GitHub.UI/Controls, you'll see they have written some custom controls, like EmojiImage (that derives from Image, and has no need for XAML), and one UserControl: HorizontalShadowDivider. Why? Because HorizontalShadowDivider has XAML associated with it and is (probably) used in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

I have read somewhere from a book (sorry forgot the book title...) that UserControl is a "block box" container.

As my understanding to the term and using your example as the basis, you can see that the `StackPanel` derived one is constrained to the ability of StackPanel to layout the two buttons - which is either Horizontal or Vertical. In the future, if this layout changes (maybe a new requirement?) you will need to create a new panel derived class (Or rewrite the existing one) and use it, say a DockPanel. This is bad.

While on the `UserControl` derived one, all you have to do is change the StackPanel to another panel type that suit the new requirement.

That makes the UserControl a block box, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As per your example, If you are using user control for one time only then it is not so useful.
But In such scenarios, If some design part is used so many times and every time you write a xaml code or any other logic to create the same UI, then User control comes to the play.